# Is there a ruby or rails method that will return the hash key when checking for the hash key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given a hash like this:

```
hash = {some_long_key: 1}
```

I want to do just this:

```
hash[:some_long_key] ? :some_long_key : nil
```

But using one method if possible...

```
hash.has_key? :some_long_key # like this
hash.check_key? :some_long_key # except return :some_long_key
```

I'd like to get back the key, not a boolean.

Pretty sure this doesn't exist but thought I'd ask.

Comment: Closest thing I found in docs is `hash.assoc(:some_long_key)&.first`

Comment: If it is known that `h[k]` is not `nil` if `h` has a key `k`, you could write `h[k] && k`, but I suspect that's not what you are after.

Comment: What is wrong with `key if hash.key?(key)`? That is short, readable and easy to understand. I cannot imagine how to name for a method that does the same and its name is that short, readable and easy to understand.

Comment: @spickermann, the question is not clear but the OP may want to avoid an `if` construct.

Comment: Yeah @CarySwoveland, Stefan's answer should be the accepted one but I don't know why mine's was that controversial (monkey-patching?) :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails adds the [`presence_in`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence_in) method for this kind of problem. It returns the receiver if it is included in the argument (via `include?`), or `nil` otherwise:

```
hash = {some_long_key: 1}

:some_long_key.presence_in(hash)
#=> :some_long_key

:some_other_key.presence_in(hash)
#=> nil
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't think there's a method for that, I would just monkey patch the `Hash` class

**EDIT**

@Stefan's answer should be the accepted one.
Rails' `presence_in` is monkey-patching the Object class (way worse than monkey-patching only the `Hash` class but I guess monkey-patching is OK for people who downvoted if Rails does it)

**EDIT**

Everybody knows (they actually don't know why but they have heard it somewhere) that monkey patching is a bad practice but it's clearly better than doing `hash.slice(:some_long_key_not_in_hash).keys.first` or `hash[:some_long_key] ? :some_long_key : nil` all over the place

```
class Hash
  def return_key_if_exists?(key)
    self.key?(key) ? key : nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe just change your answer to say if you really really want to you can monkey patch the hash class? But the correct answer is the no there is no method for that, thanks! Sorry for the downvotes?

Comment: Sagar Pandyas comment may actually be the best answer... `hash.assoc(:some_long_key)&.first` but its not super readable.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on your case (question), I don't think monkey patching is thaaat bad. you just need to know where/when to use it and put some comments around it for future reference

Comment: I mean, people downvote monkey-patching as soon as they see it. I really think it's better to know that you're monkey patching the `Hash` and be extra careful with that than to use `hash.assoc(:some_long_key)&.first` or the others `hash.key? ? :` stuff. If you're going to do it a few times it's better the `hash.key?` approach but I definitely wouldn't do `hash.assoc(:some_long_key)&.first`

Comment: @luisenrike instead of monkey patching a core class, you could just define a separate method outside the `Hash` class, e.g. `def key_presence(hash, key) ; key if hash.key?(key) ; end`

Comment: Yep, absolutely, but for some reason I thought that solution was obvious to OP. My reasoning was that if you need to do use that logic in a lot of places it would be better to have it encapsulated in the `Hash` (`hash.return_key_if_exists(:key)`) class instead of doing `SomeUtilityClass.key_presence(hash, :some_long_key)`

Comment: _"I guess monkey-patching is OK for people who downvoted if Rails does it"_ – well, the OP is using Rails (asking for a "ruby or rails method"), so the Rails patches are already there. I don't like the way Rails is patching core classes, but I do use them when working in a Rails project. But on the other hand (or maybe because Rails already patches so much), I wouldn't add more patches to core classes myself.